# How to ensure integer division gives out correct results?

Tags: javascript, floating-accuracy, integer-division

I am aware of the fact that floating point calculation is likely to be inaccurate. For example:

```
var x = 100*0.333;
```

Here x gets set to `33.300000000000004` rather than `33`. This might seem to be a minor problem, but it becomes serious if rounding is involved. For example, `Math.ceil(x)` will be incorrect - will yield `34` rather than `33`.

The problem is that I was told that JS doesn't make much difference between integers and floating points. So I'm becoming worried if there's any way to ensure that integral division is correct.

The usual formula for integer division in JS seems to be `Math.floor(n/m)`, where `n`, `m` are integers. So now let's say that `m` divides `n` evenly. Since JS treats every number as if it was a floating point number, `n/m` will return a floating point number. If this floating point number is not exact, but is even a very little bit smaller than the actual calculation result, then `Math.floor(n/m)` will get rounded down to one integer below it should.

To illustrate: if, for example, `9/3` yields `2.999999999999999` rather than `3`, then `Math.floor(9/3)` will incorrectly yield `2` rather than `3`. Well, actually, `Math.floor(9/3)` does give out correct results, but this is of course only an example; substitute `9` and `3` with any unfortunate choice of integers.

Can such scenario ever happen? If so, is there any way to ensure correct results?

Comment: All numbers in JavaScript are double-precision floating-point numbers.

Comment: Wouldn't you use `Math.round(2.99999999999)` rather than Math.floor?

Comment: @forgetso Nope. I want integer division, that rounds down. For example, I want to get `5` from `23/4`, not `6`. And I hope that `Math.floor(n/m)` will give me correct results, whether or not `n` and `m` are evenly divisible.

Comment: But `Math.round()` rounds to the closest integer, so it will give you the correct result in your hypothetical example. If the result is *supposed* to be an integer, but it comes out just a little bit off from the integer - either a little bigger or a little smaller - then `Math.round()` will work.

Comment: @Pointy Yes for sure, but then I'm going to get undesirable results in other cases, like `23/4`... I really need the results to be rounded down.

Comment: You could do it like this: `100 * (0.333 * 1000)/1000`

Comment: Also, there's the remainder operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_() Do your Math.floor() operation, then get the remainder to see what was left over.

Answer (score 2):

> Can such scenario ever happen?

No. If they are integers (i.e. floating numbers with no fractional part) and evenly divide, then the result will be exact and an integer again.
If the don't evenly divide, the result will always be greater than the exact result from integer division. You'll never get a `2.9999999…` number that was supposed to be a `3`. The floating point results are as precise as representable, rounding does not destroy the total preorder.

Comment: do you have any proof or source for your statement?

Answer (score 0):

if you want an exact integral division result. Then do this

```
Math.round((m - m%n)/n)
```

Answer (score -1):

If the value of dividing two numbers is supposed to be 3 then it will be. If the value is supposed to be 2.999999999999, it will be. Java doesn't do some kind of strange hidden rounding, up or down. If you ALWAYS need to have the value round down then Use Floor(x/y) Even if the value is 2.99999999999999999999999999999999999 it will still come back as 2. That's what Floor does. Same thing with celling. if the value is 3.0000000000000000000001 then it will be set to 4. I teach this in college, this is how it's supposed to and does work.

Comment: do you have any source or mathematical proof on this?

Comment: This answer is horribly wrong, please stop teaching this. `Math.floor(2.99999999999999999999999999999999999)` prints `3`, while `Math.floor(2.99999999999999)` prints `2`. "Strange hidden rounding" is always here and is due to the intrinsic nature of floating point numbers representation in memory. The question is not about Java, btw, but about JavaScript (even though the same phenomenon exists in Java or any other programming language).